# Shortest path with exactly $k$ edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

From Skiena's book [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/), chapter 6, problem 22:

Let $G = (V,E,w)$ be a directed weighted graph such that all the weights are positive. Let $v$ and $u$ be two vertices in $G$ and $k \leq |V|$ be an integer. Design an algorithm to find the shortest path from $v$ to $u$ that contains exactly $k$ edges. Note that the path need not be simple, and is permitted to visit vertices and edges multiple times.

This is **not homework**, its me preparing for an interview. I have no clue how to approach this.

Comment: This is a crosspost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158433/graph-design-where-the-shortest-path-must-be-k, which was closed by a moderator. I also voted to close because it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690347/shortest-path-with-a-fixed-number-of-edges

Comment: @JimBalter: 1690347 is asking for a _path_, while this is asking for a _walk_. They are quite different. I suspect the former is $NP$-Hard(two directional edges, with weights $1$ and if $k=n$ and you have a Hamiltonian Path problem), but the latter has an easy dynamic programming algorithm. I suggest you undupe those and downvote the top voted answer in 1690347 :-) which is actually an answer to 16158433.

Comment: @Aryabhata They both ask for a path through a weighted graph. But I see now that this specifies two vertices, so they're different questions. Anyway, I can't undup anything ... as I said it was closed by a moderator (for crossposting and other bad behavior).

Comment: @JimBalter: Oh sorry, I thought you were a moderator there. btw, even if the old one specified two vertices they are different problems. One asks for a path, and the other allows non-simple paths (i.e. walks). And yes, I know they are weighted paths, I was just proving NP-Hardness of the path version. Anyway...

Answer (score 13):

Since you allow non-simple paths(i.e. walks), seems like a dynamic programming algorithm will work.

For each $1 \le m \le k$, and every vertex $u$, we compute $D[m,u]$ where $D[m,u]$ is the weight of the shortest walk of length exactly $m$ starting at $v$ and ending at $u$. We are looking for $D[k,w]$.

This can be computed as

$$D[m+1, u] = \min_{x \in Pred(u)}\{D[m,x] + w[x,u]\}$$

Where $Pred(u)$ (predecessor) is the set of vertices which have an outgoing edge to $u$ and $w[x,u]$ is the weight of edge $x\to u$. You start with $D[1,u] = w(v,u)$ (allowing $\infty$).

You can add auxiliary structures to find the actual walk.

Running time: $O(k |E|)$.

This is because for each number of required edges from 1 to k, we go through the indegree of each vertex and in total, we visit all $|E|$ edges. We visit all $|E|$ for each number of the required edges ($k$) so the final run time is $O(k |E|)$ .

btw, if we wanted only simple paths, then this is probably $NP$-Hard, as we can set $k=n$ and reduce some variant of Hamiltonian Path problem to it.

Comment: I would appreciate a non-dynamic programming answer.

Comment: @Algorist: You should mention that in the question, then. But I am curious. If you are preparing for interviews, why are you discounting dynamic programming?

Comment: Since I want to learn it without dynamic programming, since I don't know dynamic programming. :(

Comment: @Algorist: Well, if the only algorithm possible uses dynamic programming, what will you do? Maybe now is a good time to learn dynamic programming? May I recommend: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf

Comment: @Aryabhata Cheers, for some reason dynamic programming wasn't covered in my undergrad degree and I need to read up on it - thanks for that link! +1

Comment: @G.Bach: Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: @Aryabhata I wonder, how does this algorithm guarantee that no edge is visited twice? Seems to me it could run around cycles. While visiting a vertex multiple times is allowed in walks, I'm not sure passing an edge multiple times is. I may be mistaken though.

Comment: @G.Bach: Non-simple paths allow edges to repeat. (I guess it depends on your definition though.)

Comment: Skiena covers this in the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RM89rxDh3XQ&list=PLOtl7M3yp-DV69F32zdK7YJcNXpTunF2b&index=17

Comment: Also here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-exactly-k-edges-directed-weighted-graph/

Answer (score 0):

Non-DP solution so it's less efficient but a bit more general: we will find shortest path using $k$ edges from $v$ to any other $u\ne v$ in $V$.

We'll make more copies of the graph so we'll have $G_0, G_1,..., G_k$ in total. Each original edge $e=(u,v)$ will be connecting $u\in G_i$ to $v \in G_i+_1$ for all $0\leq i\leq k-1$. Denote $u_i$ the copy of node $u$ in $G_i$.

Run **Dijkstra** algorithm from vertex $v_o$ (all non-negative weights) and get $\delta (v_0,u)$ the shortest path from $v_0$ to each $u$ in this "master graph", in particular to each $u_k \in G_k$. You can get now your desired shortest path.

Note that each path from $v_0$ to some $u_k$ contains exactly k edges. Complexity is $O(k\cdot(|V|+|E|))$ for constructing the graph. Since there are now $k|V|$ vertices and $k|E|$ edges Dijkstra's run time is $O(k\cdot (|E|+|V|log|V|))$ using Fibonacci heap.