# Fastest algorithm for shortest path with atmost k edges on a DAG with non-negative edge weights?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, shortest-path, dag

(Please note, this is not a duplicate to [Shortest path with exactly $k$ edges](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11503/shortest-path-with-exactly-k-edges)  OR  [Shortest path with a fixed number of edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690347/shortest-path-with-a-fixed-number-of-edges). What I want is a better algorithm)

The problem under consideration is to find single-source-shortest-path of at most $k$-edges (simple paths only). What we have is very special case: a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) $~G(V,E)~$ with positive edge weights.

> A preliminary solution to the problem is to run Bellman-Ford to $k$-iterations with **parallel relaxation** on all edges.

Bellman-Ford solution for finding usual shortest-paths, is generally known to be worse in complexity for graphs with positive edge weights. But it is the only algorithm, which possesses the very special property of identifying all $k$-edge optimal paths after $k$-iterations, provided we relax the edges parallelly. This eventually finds all shortest simple paths after at most $|V|-1$ iterations.

So simply by stopping the Bellman-Ford algorithm after $k$ iterations, we can find the desired shortest-path of at most $k$-edges from the given source. Also note that, Bellman-Ford algorithm is a classic instance of Dynamic Programming(DP) and the truncated version proposed above is a DP as well.

It seems dynamic-programming/Bellman-Ford algorithm (truncated to k-iterations & parallel relaxing of edges) will solve this problem with $O(k|E|)$ complexity. But can we do better at least on a graph with non-negative weights? At least, for a Directed Acyclic Graph(DAG) with non-negative weights!

I think it is a legitimate question to ask for a better algorithm, given that we have a much better alternative for usual shortest-path algorithms on graphs with positive weights, namely the Dijkstra's algorithm. Interesting question here is this: Does it extend to finding $k$-edge optimal paths?  This is definitely not immediate, since unlike Bellman-Ford, Dijkstra's doesn't have this property of $k$-edge optimality at $any$ iteration.

(Worse thing is that even the constant-factor saving modifications to Bellman-Ford, proposed by Yen, are no more useful for truncated Bellman-Ford.
I have a strong hope to have something better!)

Comment: You mention Dijkstra; have you tried determining the runtime of Dijkstra if you cut after $k$ hops?

Comment: @Raphael Hmm. Its obvious that using Dijkstra is wrong here; simply because it doesn't have the k-hop optimality property after k-iterations. And of course, Dijkstra algorithm's full cycle itself will have less complexity than Bellman-ford, but its useless and that is the point of the question --- To suggest alternative.

Comment: I think you are dismissing the idea too quickly. $k$ iterations won't always cover all paths with at most $k$ edges, but that's not the point -- some number of iterations will, and you don't ever have to consider (edge-)longer paths.

Comment: @D.W. and Raphael: Thanks for the comments, hope my edits will clarify your points.

Comment: Again, I do not think that $k$ iterations of Bellman-Ford solves this problem.  That approach will indeed take into account all paths of length $\le k$, but also some paths of length $>k$ (depending upon exactly what order you relax the edges in each Bellman-Ford iteration).  So truncated Bellman-Ford will output a lower bound on the distances you want, but not necessarily the right values.  In other words, I think your statements in the 3rd and 4th paragraphs are not correct.  Your problem *can* be solved with dynamic programming in $O(k |E|)$ time, but not (truncated) Bellman-Ford.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the explanation & I see what you are saying now. My mention is the basic implementation of Bellman-Ford, which can be simply written as [in here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Algorithm). What you said is an enhanced version of Bellman-Ford which is [due to Yen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Improvements). The original version, ensures that at $k$th iteration, you have only paths with at most $k$ edges enumerated and best ones are picked. The other one will be faster (up to 1/4), but destroys intermediate optimality.

Comment: @D.W. By the way, the wiki page itself has the proof of my statement. You may find it [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness) as the second point in the lemma.

Comment: @Harish, again, what you write is not correct.  I'm not talking about Yen's variant; I'm talking about the basic Bellman-Ford. The basic Bellman-Ford simply does not have the property you assert.  Take a look at the second point of the lemma you link to; it says that the number output by Bellman-Ford after $i$ iterations is *at most* the number you want (not "exactly equal to").  In other words, as I wrote earlier, Bellman-Ford gives you a lower bound on the value you want, not the exact value you want.  Perhaps you might like to try to work through a bunch of examples....

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for the details. 
You said it right, "at most $i$ edges" is exactly what I want and the question has been stating the same!! The Question is about finding a path of at most $k$ edges NOT "exactly" $k$ edges. After $k$ iterations, the paths cannot go beyond $k$ edges and all thus far identified paths are optimal under the the constraint: #edges <= $k$. If this is wrong, then I certainly have to do some examples :). In any case, thanks a lot for your patient answers.

Comment: @D.W. As per 2nd point in the lemma at the wiki entry [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness): I believe, after $i$ iterations, ($a$) "path-length at most shortest" $\equiv$ "a shortest-path";
($b$) "path-length at most shortest, with at most $k$ edges" $\equiv$ "a shortest-path, with atmost $k$ edges". If you don't think I am bothering you, kindly do explain, where am I wrong!!

Comment: @Harish, 1. Yes, I already know the distinction between "at most $k$ edges" and "exactly $k$ edges" and I already took that into account -- that's not what I'm referring to.  2. The lemma says "the output of the algorithm" is $\le$ (*not* $=$) "the length of the shortest path that uses at most $k$ edges.  To count as a solution to your problem, you'd need it to be $=$.  3. I encourage you to spend some time working through a bunch of examples on your own.  Try it for yourself.  You'll see.

Comment: @D.W. Okay hopefully the last query:
 A "path" $\mathbb{P}$ (guaranteed by lemma-1) is found from source to destination with 
1. $\mathbb{P}$ has at most k-edges
2. $\mathbb{P}$ has length <= shortest path of at most k-edges.
what can that path be?

My answer: 1. $\mathbb{P}$ is a valid path of desired kind (i.e. $\leq k$ edges from source to dest) 2. Its length is "**equal to**" the shortest path (there is no path shorter than shortest). _So thats exactly the path we wanted_!!!!

Comment: @D.W. Thanks a lot & I found the problem. I have been doing is a parallel update on all vertices. But the algorithm stated does a sequential update of vertices. Then it cannot be correct. Updating the Question to reflect this issue.